# Getting critical error when installing Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation

My hoster forced me to upgrade my Wordpress site because it was fairly old. I decided to upgrade to PHP 8.1. It caused issues with the website, so I figured I'd rebuild the whole website since it's a simple website. I deleted all the existing files and uploaded the 5.8.2 WordPress install files. Then I changed all the permissions to 0755. I created a fresh database for the install.

At first, the setup would appear. I would go through the install, but when I clicked install after entering all the database info, I got "There has been a critical error on this website." I recreated the .htaccess file to the default and tried again. Now I get this error just hitting the domain, no more setup screens. The site does redirect to the /wp-admin/setup-config.php file. I don't have a wp-config.php file in the directory, just the sample one. I tried creating a wp-config.php with the correct info, but same error. I also tried adding the debug options, increasing PHP memory, etc. Same error. I don't get any error logs.

Does anyone now how to get an error log or can help with ideas on how to create a fresh WordPress site? I did change the PHP versions to older ones, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a backup of your file ,then fallow the fallowing instruction.

- Rename your plugin one by one and refresh the website.
  this issue due to the unsupported plugin ,that is installed in your wordpress website.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but there are no plugins installed. Are you suggesting the default WordPress install has unsupported plugins in it? I'll try removing them and seeing if that helps. I suspect it might be related to a permissions issue. I'll keep tinkering and update you.

Answer (score 0):

1- Make a backup copy of the files and from the old database

2- After that, download these files on your PC

3- Install WordPress again

4- Replace the wp-content file with the old one

5- Clean the new database and import the old database through phpMyAdmin

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but there are no plugins installed. The files are just from the default Wordpress as this is a fresh install. The database has no tables in it and I don't want the old database, I want a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem installing an older version of Xampp, with previous version of php, MySQL and Apache. I give up version 8.1.1

XAMPP 7.4.27 / PHP 7.4.27
https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: Agreed. WordPress isn't ready for PHP 8.x. It wasn't the source of my issue, but downgrading PHP did solve a lot of other issues.

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong on the hosting side. The source of the issue was indeed that WordPress could not write to the config file. Even the hoster was unable to delete the files. We ended up deleting the entire root directory and starting from scratch. Now it's all good.

The lesson learned is that one of the sources of the "There has been a critical error on this website." error is that WordPress is unable to write/edit files. It's also why it could not write an error log. WordPress could have been more descriptive here.